# Postgres server doesn't launch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I try to set up Postgres for rails in order to be able to deploy on Heroku. I am actually resuming rails tutorials and am a bit lost (am no programmer)

In PgadminIII I try to connect to the single server available (POSTGRESQL 9.3 Localhost 5432)

It asks for a password (which I am guessing at the moment) and shows error:

```
server doesn't listen
```

My questions are:

- Is the password the super user password? (the only one I own at the moment)
- what is the purpose of the super user password?
- How can I recover the password that activates the server?

Answer (score 0):

Follow up this tutorial from command line and that way you can alter the password and create a new user with custom password.

Actually by default there will be template1 database that creates postgresql while intalling it for the first time and then you can create your database.

First you do all the steps mention in this tutorial and then from you applicatio you eed to create a database like

```
rake db:create:all
```

[Postgresql Tutorial](http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2009/06/postgresql-how-to-reset-user-name.html)

super user password need to setup postgresql on you system, by which you can get access of super admin.

Password recovery command is also there in tutorial.

-------Updates---------

There are two possible reasons for this: either the server isn’t running at all. Simply start it.

The other non-trivial cause for this message is that the server isn’t configured to accept TCP/IP requests on the address shown.

Check your postgresql.conf file, add a line

> tcpip = true

or if it is already there as "FALSE" value then just replace above line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: rake db:create or rake db:setup give error "server doesnt listen ... is the server running on host localhost and accepting tcp/ip on port 5432" - this is what i thought i could fix by connecting to the server through Pgadmin ..

Comment: There are two possible reasons for this: either the server isn’t running at all. Simply start it.

The other non-trivial cause for this message is that the server isn’t configured to accept TCP/IP requests on the address shown.

Comment: thanks for your help. typed NET START POSTGRESQL-x64-9.3 and got "requested service has already been started" (as I never did any such command before). I guess i need to actually learn Postgre in deep as I have no idea how this works. (Or maybe rollback to mysql and drop Heroku) thanks anyway